# C# linq how to get all the first elements of a nested dynamic list?

Tags: c#, list, linq, dynamic

I have a 2D nested list `List<list<dynamic>>`, I'd like to get first elements of every second level list and form a new `List<dynamic>`.

I know `.first()` gets the first element of a list, but how can I apply it on multiple sub lists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `mainList.Select(subList => subList.First()).ToList()` ?

Comment: Just as info: @LasseV.Karlsen's solution will raise an `Exception` if sublist is empty.

Comment: do `Where(subList => subList.Count > 0)` before select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper and efficient way of doing this is as follows:

```
mainList.Select(subList => subList?.First()).OfType<dynamic>();
```

This will take care of `null` lists and `null` elements

If you want to select all the elements of sublists try following

```
mainlist.Select(subList => subList).OfType<List<dynamic>>();
```

This will only take care of `null` lists

Comment: i Guess his problem is getting multiple elements from each sublist

Comment: okay @AmjadSaab . He has to mentioned problem statement clearly whether he wants to take first or all or any specified numbers of elements from each of sublists

Comment: you r right!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable s =  listOfLists.Where(lists => lists.Any())
.Select(array => array.First());

Explanation:

1. First fetch the list of arrays where there are any records  by using lists => lists.Any()
2. Then select the first item from each list and return.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

try this please if you want to take the first two elements of each list, and the more elements you want you can increase the integer in the .Take().

```
List<List<string>> originalList = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>(){"1","1","1"},
    new List<string>(){"2","2"},    
};    

    var FirtTwoElementsList = originalList.Select(x => x.Take(2)).ToList();
    List<string> FinalList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in FirtTwoElementsList)
    {
       FinalList.AddRange(item.ToList<string>());
    }
```

Comment: Iam just trying to help because he asked for an answer dear @CaiusJard